# How to define and call a multi argument function with from Fable

Tags: javascript, f#, fable-f#

I'm trying to call Redux.createStore with 2 arguments, the following code simplifies the signature but I am unable to get FSharp to understand what I want:

```
[<Import("*","Redux")>]
module redux =
    let createStore: (System.Func<int,int> -> int) = jsNative

let store = redux.createStore 22//no idea what to do here
```

So lets say I want to define createStore as a function that takes 2 ints, not a tuple of 2 ints and not a function that takes one int and returns a function that takes one int (partially apply 2 ints). No, it is a native function that takes 2 arguments (say ints) and returns an int.

In the examples there is a redux example that is only ever used taking one parameter.

The [documentation](http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html) shows how to create a function taking multiple arguments but not how to define the type nor how to call such a function.

The example does show the definition with multiple arguments but never calls it so still don't know how to call a js function that takes multiple arguments.

Comment: Your `createStore` function is a function of one argument: it takes a function and returns an `int`. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin For simplicity sake let's assume that createStore takes 2 parameters: 1: (a:int, b:int):int (typescript notation so no tuples or partial apply but 2 arguments). and an int. It will return an int. In reality it will take different types ( https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/master/samples/browser/redux-todomvc/redux-todomvc.fsx#L49 ) but let's just keep it simple for now as I'm trying to figure out how to define a js function that takes 2 parameters and call it with 2 parameters.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin By the way; thank you for your reply. Was trying to see what transpiling typescript definition does but it seems to transpile the definition of JS functions taking multiple arguments to functions that take tuples (one tuple argument) Since createStore is from an external library  (redux)I have to give Fable a definition for it, and since I want to call the function I need to call it. It's late here so I will go to bed and check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I'm trying to figure out how to define a js function that takes 2 parameters and call it with 2 parameters.

The answer is, just do exactly what you said:

```
[<Import("*","Redux")>]
module redux =
    let createStore (a: int, b: int): int = jsNative

let store = redux.createStore (22, 42)
```

Except for the code example, I can't add anything else, because I'm not sure what your actual question was: whether you found something non-obvious about this (what?), of if you tried this and it didn't work somehow (how?), or something else (what?).

Comment: Yes, that workes, thank you; but now the applicationHandler is partially applied. I added an answer with the full type annotation (except for the return type that should be Redux.store). Using a JS Interop file to take care of wrapping/unwrapping partially applied functions to something that works with Redux.

Answer (score 0):

Getting really tired of trying to define a type that F# and Fable understand and then trying to call it.

For now I created a JavaScript file called JSI.js:

```
/**
 * JavaScipt Interop to call complex JavaScipt library methods 
 * where I have no clue how to define the type for in F#/Fable
 */
define(["exports","redux"],function(exports,Redux){
  exports.createStore = 
    (fn)=>
    (initialStore)=>{
      return Redux.createStore(
        (action,state)=>fn(action)(state)
        ,initialStore
      );
    }
});
```

Then in main.fsx:

```
[<Import("*","../js/JSI")>]
module JSI =
    let createStore: 
      (
        (AppController.ApplicationModel -> Action -> AppController.ApplicationModel)
          -> AppController.ApplicationModel
          -> int
      ) = jsNative

let store = 
  JSI.createStore 
    applicationHandler
    AppController.defaultModel
```

That would wrap/unwrap F# partially applied functions to something with multiple arguments to be used by Redux.